# How to enable Stateful Retry using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka and RetryTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-retry, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am wondering if there is a way to enable Stateful RetryTemplate using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.

I noticed that there is a constructor

```java
RetryingMessageListenerAdapter(MessageListener<K, V> messageListener, RetryTemplate retryTemplate, RecoveryCallback<? extends Object> recoveryCallback, boolean stateful)
```

Debugging through this code, I noticed that boolean value `false` is passed into `stateful` parameter using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.

Related links: [KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/a66955513938d8dadbfc462a1ef0848e5a1bf5d4/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/inbound/KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java#L297), [RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/c0dfe83c0a55f5ddaffb340fa77506718850aa1e/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/adapter/RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java#L82)

I have a few questions regarding this topic.

1. Is there a way to set `RetryingMessageListenerAdapter`'s member `stateful` as true through application.yml or `ListenerContainerCustomizer`?
2. Is there a way to disable `RetryTemplate` using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka? I think the closest I found was to override `max-attempts` to 1 in my `@StreamRetryTemplate`.
3. If I am using `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` provided by spring-kafka, is there any benefit or reason why I should set `stateful` as true since `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` is already a stateful error handling mechanism?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stateful retry is no longer needed now that the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` has retry and backoff capabilities.

Yes, to disable retry in the binder, set `maxAttempts=1` and configure the STCEH appropriately.